# Access class inside function

Tags: node.js, function, class, ecmascript-6

I have a `ready()` function which contain an es6 class.
I would like to instantiate this class outside the function, however I didn't succeed in making this working.

I don't want to use return function because the function can have more than one class.

Here is an example of what i want to do :

```
function ready(api) {
    class A extends api.C {
        contructor() {
            this.foo = "bar";
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        contructor() {
            this.bar = "foo";
        }
    }
}

let classA = ready.A; // Here is the problem : I would like to access to the class prototype
```

The reason is my application have some plugins using `remi` npm package, and I want to export classes shared between all plugins.
I don't know if it's possible, anybody have an idea ?

**[EDIT] :**

First thanks all for your hep, In fact I need to be more accurate in my issue.
That's true, I can return back both classes through a classic `return`. But let me explain what I want to do exactly :

- I have a core application which have some plugins. Plugins can be internally integrated to core, or through a classic NPM install. As explained above I use `remi` plugin loader.
- The desired rules are the following : Each plugin get a core API access through a callback. Each plugin can expose classes to be used in other plugins. Each plugins can have inheritance for those exposed (ie exported) plugins.

Here is how I describe a plugin :

```
/**
 * This class is a sample plugin
 * @class
 */
class Sample {
    constructor(api) {
        this.api = api;
    }


    /**
     * Shows a test log
     */
    test() {
        console.log("======> I'm working !");
    }
}

function loaded(api) {
    let s = new Sample(api);
}

module.exports = (api, options) => {

};

module.exports.attributes = {
    loadedCallback: loaded,
    name: "sample-plugin",
    version: "0.0.0",
    category: "misc",
    description: "I'm a sample plugin",
    classes: [Sample]
};
```

The core plugin manager will load the first time all plugins, and will register into an array all classes protoypes exported into the `classes` attributes property.
Then the `loaded(api)` function is called and classes can be instantiated through `api.classes` object.
In another plugin, I can do this :

```
function loaded(api) {
    let sample = new api.classes.Sample(api);   
}
```

And I can instantiate a class described in another plugin.
That's the idea.
However I would like to do a more complex API usage with the multiple inheritance, for example :

- Plugin A exposes class A
- Plugin B exposes class B extends A
- Plugin C exposes class C extends B

**To be more clear, I would like to export globally some classes, to get a shared access between NPM modules**

Comment: *I don't want to use return function because the function can have more than one class* - what do you mean by this? Why not `return { A, B };` ?

Comment: No, that's obviously not possible without even *calling* `ready` and passing in an API to actually create the class in the first place. Also, why not just use the class on the inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can return class `A` from `ready` function, so after calling `ready` you can access `A` class

```
function ready(api) {
    class A extends api.C {
        contructor() {
            this.foo = "bar";
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        contructor() {
            this.bar = "foo";
        }
    }
    return {A : A};
}

let classA = ready(api).A;
```